# Python: How find the index in list by its part?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
result = []
reader = ['sdsd-sdds', 'asaad', 'deded - wdswd', '123' ]
str_1 = 'deded -'
for row in reader:
    if row.index(str_1) in row:
        result.extend(row.index(str_1) + 1)
print(result)
```

how to find the index by its part, the program should print ['123']

Comment: I indicated the most important problem - the program does not search for an index in its part

Comment: `if row.index(str_1) in row` This will never be true, as `index()` returns an integer.

Comment: @JohnGordon And what is the problem with that? Try `if 1: print('True')`

Comment: `row.index(str_1)` returns an integer, so you're actually doing `if 5 in row:`, which will never be true.

Comment: OK, that was an `OutOfCoffeeError` on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
result = []
reader = ['sdsd-sdds', 'asaad', 'deded - wdswd', '123' ]
str_1 = 'deded -'
for x in reader:
    if str_1 in x:
        result.append(reader[reader.index(x) + 1])
print(result)
```

If you want to stop after finding the first one you should use a break after finding a value:

```
result = []
reader = ['deded - wdswd', 'asaad', 'deded - wdswd', '123' ]
str_1 = 'deded -'
for x in reader:
    if str_1 in x:
        result.append(reader[reader.index(x) + 1])
        break
print(result)
```

Comment: And if you define `reader = ['deded - wdswd', 'asaad', 'deded - wdswd', '123' ]` you get `['asaad', 'asaad']` with your approach.

Comment: Good appreciation, but does he want only the first one to come out, or all the values that meet the condition?

Comment: Anyway, I've edited the answer and added the solution to what you've seen. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The statement `row.index(str1)` does not give you the index of `row` in `reader`; it gives you the index of `str1` in `row`, and this is useless for what you're trying to do, which is to get the next item *after* row in `reader` once you've found a match (and it doesn't matter where within the string the match is found AFAICT).

You could do this by doing `reader.index(row)` but it'd be easier to just enumerate `reader` so that you already have the index available.  Using `index` is not necessarily at all since you can also just do `str_1 in row`:

```
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if str_1 in row:
        result.append(reader[i+1])
```

Comment: Then you might have to explain what you want with other words or a second example. I really don't understand what you mean with "str_1 is part of index". This code will give you the output you asked for.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but this code does produce `result == ['123']`.  Maybe your example isn't representative of what you're trying to do?